# Websocket is closed before connection established

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, socket.io, amazon-elb

My application sits behind an elastic application load balancer and nginx server. When trying to connect to socket.io from chrome I receive a WebSocket is closed before the connection is established message and a 400 error.. This does not seem to occur when connecting directly through nginx. Additionally I have found that this error also does not occur when using a firefox browser. Is there a setting I am missing on the load balancer? I have tried sticky sessions/etc.. but that does not seem to resolve the issue.

Th

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out. After adding the following to my config file it seemed to work consistantly.  proxy_set_header Origin "";